# How to force network.target to wait for DHCP with systemd-networkd?

Tags: networking, systemd, dhcp

I'm using systemd-networkd to configure my interfaces:

```
[Match]
Name=enp3s0

[Network]
DHCP=v4
```

It works quite well except that at boot, some services are not waiting for DHCP to finish. For instances my NFS-mounted directories and nginx fail because there is no network at the time they boot.

Is there a way to force network.target to wait for DHCP?

---

Note from the editor. According to the [documentation](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/NetworkTarget/):

> Many network management solutions provide a way to unconditionally pull in network-online.target, and thus upgrading the effect of network.target to the effect of network-online.target.
>
> If you use systemd-networkd you can do this by enabling systemd-networkd-wait-online.service:
>
> `systemctl enable systemd-networkd-wait-online.service`

However I tried this and it ***did not*** make services depending on `network.target` wait for DHCP. It only made services which explicitly depend on `network-online.target` wait for DHCP, and in fact it is required to make that work.

Comment: The other services should be waiting for the network, with `{After,Wants}=network-online.target`.

Comment: @jasonwryan I can edit my own services, but what about NFS mount for instance ? There is no service file for that. Or sshd.service, should I edit all of them ? Isn't there any way to force network.target = network-online.target ?

Comment: Do you need to wait for DHCP? Can you assign a static IP?

Comment: Yes, I need to wait. I switched from static IP to DHCP and that's caused all the problems. No, I do not want to assign static IPs.

Comment: I'm also having this problem. I have `{After,Wants}=network-online.target` in my service unit, and `systemd-networkd-wait-online.service` is enabled. Still, my service immediately starts after the links is activated, but without having an ipv4 address via DHCP.

Answer (score 7):

When using systemd-networkd, to make sure that all interfaces are up and have an IP address assigned use:

```
systemctl enable systemd-networkd-wait-online.service
```

Someone else may be using NetworkManager, in which case that would be:

```
systemctl enable NetworkManager-wait-online.service
```

See: http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/NetworkTarget/

Comment: I did this, still no luck...

Comment: Maybe it's because the interface also has an IPv6 address, and `systemd-neworkd-wait-online` thinks that's enough: https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2016-July/037201.html

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the definition of "online" in this context is defined in `.network` file.

```
[Link]
RequiredForOnline=routable
```

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.network.html#RequiredForOnline=
https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.network.html#RequiredFamilyForOnline=
`RequiredForOnline` has a default value of `yes` which I cannot find a definition of it. But you should set to one of the values listed here: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/networkctl.html
I choose `routable` because it will wait for an IP.

Answer (score 3):

According to the man page for [systemd-networkd-wait-online.service](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-networkd-wait-online.service.html):

*By default, it will wait for all links it is aware of and which are managed by systemd-networkd.service(8) to be fully configured or failed, and for at least one link to be online. Here, online means that the link's operational state is equal or higher than "degraded". The threshold can be configured by --operational-state= option.*

So if you want a specific link to be fully configured and routable to be considered "online", you could edit `/lib/systemd/system/systemd-networkd-wait-online.service` and change `ExecStart` to:

```
ExecStart=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-networkd-wait-online --operational-state=routable
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used `systemd-networkd` specifically before, but `systemd` definitely should be able to resolve this by adjusting the `systemd` service file that `systemd-networkd` uses.

## Finding Service File

If you run:

```
systemctl status systemd-networkd
```

You should get output that looks similar to this (using `systemd-modules-load.service` as an example because I don't have `systemd-networkd`):

```
systemd-modules-load.service - Load Kernel Modules
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-modules-load.service; static)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since So 2013-08-25 11:48:13 CEST; 32s ago
 Docs: man:systemd-modules-load.service(8).
       man:modules-load.d(5)
Process: 15630 ExecStart=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-modules-load (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

The second line tells you the location of the service file (in the example it's `/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-modules-load.service`). The service file determines when in the `systemd` hierarchy things should be started.

## Modifying Service File

If you open this file in a text editor there are 3 very important sections:

- `[Unit]`
- `[Service]`
- `[Install]`

The `[Unit]` section can contain `After` and `Requires` directives. `After` forces the service to start after another `systemd` unit, `Requires` forces another `systemd` unit to be started if it's not already enabled (but doesn't force an ordering).

So if you locate the `systemd-networkd` service file, determine which unit you want `systemd-networkd` to start after, and add to the `[Unit]` section you should be set:

```
[Unit]
...
Requires=[unit name]
After=[unit name]
```

With this method you can force the `systemd-networkd` service to start after any other unit.

## Other Concerns

You say your network mounts fail, if you're mounting the via `/etc/fstab` do their entries contain the `_netdev` option?

Comment: This doesn't address the question at all. Also you just created a circular dependency where the thing that brings up network interfaces won't run until the network interfaces are up.

Comment: @ali1234 "Is there a way to force systemd-networkd to wait for DHCP or another target to wait for in the other service files" The `systemd` service file is what determines when the service is started, so I wouldn't say it "doesn't address the question at all". I'll concede that `network-online.target` is not the unit needed here, but the rest of the answer is still valid. I'll take out the `network-online.target` mention though and look into the dhcpclient a little more. Seems like the `network-functions` normally call `/sbin/dhcpclient` which `systemd-networkd` is probably also doing.

Comment: The person who originally asked this question phrased it very badly. They actually want to make network.target wait until an interface has been assigned an address on DHCP. According to the documentation linked in the other answer 'systemctl enable systemd-networkd-wait-online.service' does that. But in reality it does not.

Comment: @ali1234 A bit of a hack way to achieve this would be a new `systemd` service that is before `systemd-networkd`, with an `ExecPre` calling a script that loops trying to call `dhcpclient` on the first interface until it suceeds. Even if the first interface isn't DHCP it'll get overwritten when `systemd-network` does start. This assumes `systemd-networkd` is mostly just responsible for configuring the interfaces.

Comment: `systemd-networkd` does all interface management from bringing up the interfaces to doing DHCP so that would still cause a circular dependency.

Comment: @ali1234 If `systemd-networkd` is responsible for enabling DHCP, and DHCP isn't ready by the time it's trying to enable the interfaces I would say that's a bug in `systemd-networkd` and should probably be raised to their site.

Comment: DHCP fetches an IP address from the network, therefore it CANNOT work until the network interfaces are up. `systemd-networkd` brings the network interfaces up. Therefore if you force `systemd-networkd` to wait until DHCP has been performed, you have created a circular dependency. This is not a bug, it is a fundamental fact of how DHCP works.

Comment: @ali1234 DHCP is a broadcast request, which the DHCP server responds via MAC address, the interfaces need to be functional, but the order of operations should be `functional interfaces -> make DHCP requests -> config static addresses -> confirm DHCP requests/static sets are done`

Comment: Exactly and `systemd-networkd` is responsible for the first item in your list, which is also called "bringing up interfaces" as it is what happens when you run "ifconfig eth0 up" (without supplying an IP address).

Comment: @ali1234 I'm saying if `systemd-networkd` doesn't do all of these before continuing on, then that sounds like a bug in `systemd-networkd` (that it can be finished before it's DHCP interfaces are up at all)

Answer (score 1):

Most linux variants use Network Manager with `systemd` using `NetworkManager-wait-online.service` to determine whether or not the network is up. If this is the case, you can edit `/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager-wait-online.service` and change:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/nm-online -s -q --timeout=30
```

To:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/nm-online -q --timeout=30
```

The -s option means: Wait for NetworkManager startup to complete, rather than waiting for network connectivity specifically.

Removing it will give a better indication of the network status and systemd can wait for it to come up before starting the dependant services.