# mount smb share after wireguard with fstab or systemd

Tags: systemd, fstab, cifs, smb, wireguard

I'm trying to mount an SMB-share after a wireguard connection has been established. Therefore I did the following things:

- created a wireguard config
- made systemd start the connection on startup
  `systemctl enable wg-quick@wg0.service`
- added the following entry to fstab

```
//192.168.0.10/home /mnt/smb cifs x-systemd.after=wg-quick@wg0.service,credentials=/home/user/.smbcredentials,vers=3.0,uid=user,pid=user,users,_netdev 0 0
```

After rebooting the network share is not mounted. With the knowledge that every entry in fstab is converted into a systemd-unit I checked the status of the unit `systemctl status mnt-smb.mount`.

```
● mnt-smb.mount - /mnt/smb
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/fstab; generated; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2022-02-09 16:55:28 CET; 1min 17s ago
    Where: /mnt/smb
     What: //192.168.0.10/home
     Docs: man:fstab(5)
           man:systemd-fstab-generator(8)
  Process: 496 ExecMount=/bin/mount //192.168.0.10/home /mnt/smb -t cifs -o x-systemd.after=wg-quick@wg0.service,credentials=/home/user/.smbcredentials,vers=3.0,uid=user,gid=user,users,_netdev (code=exited, status=32)

Feb 09 16:55:28 homeserver systemd[1]: Mounting /mnt/smb...
Feb 09 16:55:28 homeserver systemd[1]: mnt-smb.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited status=32
Feb 09 16:55:28 homeserver systemd[1]: Failed to mount /mnt/smb.
Feb 09 16:55:28 homeserver systemd[1]: mnt-smb.mount: Unit entered failed state.
```

A look into `dmesg` gave the following information:

```
[   17.612210] Key type cifs.spnego registered
[   17.612253] Key type cifs.idmap registered
[   17.758816] wireguard: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[   17.775249] wireguard: WireGuard 0.0.20191206 loaded. See www.wireguard.com for information.
[   17.775273] wireguard: Copyright (C) 2015-2019 Jason A. Donenfeld <Jason@zx2c4.com>. All Rights Reserved.
[   27.752548] CIFS VFS: Error connecting to socket. Aborting operation.
[   27.752576] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -115
```

Based on the following [question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30054880/what-does-cifs-mount-failed-w-return-code-111-indicate), i assume that 115 means "in progress". I have seen the same behaviour if the wireguard vpn connection was not up.

Having a look into the generated unit file:

```
# Automatically generated by systemd-fstab-generator

[Unit]
SourcePath=/etc/fstab
Documentation=man:fstab(5) man:systemd-fstab-generator(8)
Before=remote-fs.target

[Mount]
What=//192.168.0.10/home
Where=/mnt/smb
Type=cifs
Options=x-systemd.after=wg-quick@wg0.service,credentials=/home/user/.smbcredentials,vers=3.0,uid=user,gid=user,users,_netdev
```

If I run `mount -a` after login, everything works as expected. So I think it is a timing issue between the units. Therefore I also created an own systemd unit and removed the entry from fstab:

```
[Unit]
Description=Homeserver SMB
Before=remote-fs.target
After=wg-quick@wg0.service
Requires=wg-quick@wg0.service

[Mount]
Type=cifs
What=//192.168.0.10/home
Where=/mnt/smb
Options=credentials=/home/user/.smbcredentials,vers=3.0,uid=user,gid=user,users

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Moved it to `/etc/systemd/system/mnt-smb.mount` and activated it via `systemctl enable mnt-smb.mount`. This worked for one reboot, but stopped working after the next reboot.

**Questions:**

- How could this timing issue be resolved?
- What systemd options could be used in the unit file or in fstab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the interface setup by wireguard isn't ready just because the service started.  Your issue may be [related to this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/624987/ssh-fails-to-start-when-listenaddress-is-set-to-wireguard-vpn-ip) in which case the solution is to wait for the virtual device.

```
After=network.target wg-quick@wg0.service
Requires=sys-devices-virtual-net-wg0.device
```

Comment: Thank you for the hint - this made it working! One more, related quesion - how could the same be accomplished without wireguard? The target network-online.target doesn't seem to work for that.

Comment: @nioerd See if [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/157529/how-to-force-network-target-to-wait-for-dhcp-with-systemd-networkd) helps.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I already tried `systemctl enable systemd-networkd-wait-online.service` but it does not seem to change anything. Could this be caused by using dhcpcd for setting a static IP?

Comment: @nioerd That should have done it.  Maybe try reading through [this](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/NetworkTarget/).

Comment: I got it working. The target `network-online.target` only worked for me after setting up systemd to configure the network interfaces. A good tutorial could be found here: [https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/108592](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/108592)