# Mount smb/cifs shares only after openvpn client has been established

Tags: systemd, systemd-networkd, systemd-unit

I'm trying to accomplish almost exactly what was asked here: [mount smb share after wireguard with fstab or systemd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/689975/mount-smb-share-after-wireguard-with-fstab-or-systemd)

The only difference is that I'm using openvpn rather than wireguard.  I'm attempting to apply the same solution that was given in that question but it appears it's still not working.

Essentially, I want my device to perform the following tasks in the following order:

1. Boot up and connect to WIFI
2. Obtain an IP address from the router using DHCP.
3. Establish a VPN connection to my house.
4. mount SMB shares.

I don't want any of those steps to occurr that the same time, but only after each step has finished.

I've managed to get the first three steps working.  But it appers that CIFS shares are trying to be mounted too soon still.

I can see in dmesg the following:

```
[   18.395918] CIFS: Attempting to mount //192.168.188.4/share/Multimedia/Music
[   20.806050] tun: Universal TUN/TAP device driver, 1.6
```

This tells me that the tun interface is coming up after CIFS has already attempted to mount its shares.

Following the thread I linked to in the beginning, I created the following systemd mount unit file mnt-ChenbroNAS-Music.mount:

```
[Unit]
Description=Music SMB
Before=remote-fs.target
After=network.target network-online.target openvpn-client@vpn.service
Requires=sys-devices-virtual-net-tun0.device
Wants=network-online.target openvpn-client@vpn.service

[Mount]
Type=cifs
What=//192.168.188.4/share/Multimedia/Music
Where=/mnt/ChenbroNAS/Music
Options=vers=2.0,credentials=/home/usr/.smbCredentials,uid=1000,gid=1000,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I put the unit file into /etc/systemd/system and ensured it was enabled.  I really think I'm just getting the "Before=", "After=", "Requires=", and "Wants=" all mixed up and not sure if they're in the right order.

You can also see that I've added the "Requires=sys-devices-virtual-net-tun0.device" line in there hoping that it'll verify that there's an actual tun interface first.

Do I need to also adjust whatever service CIFS is using to start after openvpn-client@vpn.service?  I'm not sure what service that would be.  There doesn't appear to be cifs.service file anywhere.

I believe my device is using systemd-networkd and NOT systemd-NetworkManager.  I've been sure to enable the systemd-networkd-wait-online.service as well.

Comment: It has occurred to me that I could edit my openvpn conf file to run a script after the connection is established.  The script could simply execute the mount command.  I'm not sure if the script would need elevated privileges to work though.  And if so, how I'd ensure that it'd execute successfully.  Thoughts anyone?